# Best solution architecture for: Intelligent chat to retrieve information from specific sources

Tags: machine-learning, computer-architecture, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to design best solution for a chat application based on LLM model which has set of functions and based on user input can retrieve the information.

I would like to ask you for some proposals regarding this because I am running of ideas. I've implemented PoC application where I am storing in mongo db collection with configuration for specific flow and the matching question based on vectors something like:

**Prompt**: "What are available account numbers"

**Vector**: [vectors for question],

**Flow**: what to do to get the account numbers.

Now when the user puts something on a chat I am getting closest matching question and generate the output for the user. This looks good but it's not a perfect solution.

Problems:

Some functions might require information from the user so the tool needs to ask for these details.

Some flows might require merging functions like. I want details for my transactions: It should first get the transactions for user and then details for each transaction and generate output.

I was thinking about introducing Azure semantic-kernel. I will define sets of functions and semantic-kernel based on conversation history with the user will decide about the actions. I am not convinced about this so I would like to check with you maybe you experienced similar problem and you found some good solutions for this. I expect this tool to be flexible and maintainable cause I don't know yet how many flows it needs to support. Probably some database data fetching, calling APIs and much more, so it has to be extendable.

What you think?

**If the question doesnt match this stackexchange please give me a hint where I can discuss this.**

Comment: https://github.com/NVIDIA/NeMo-Guardrails

Comment: @D.W. and Rafal, if this is about using existing LLMs, customizing them, deploying them, etc, it belongs to GenAI.SE

Comment: We have a gpt-4 llm model so it's rather to build an app which will use llm model internally to lead intelligent conversation with the user, but the app itself hits specific database/ apis based on user request to get the data. So we are looking for a good framework which will get what the user wants, then ask a user for arguments if required to get some data and then retrieve the data and display on a chat. So we need to have some template matcher for the questions and intelligent chat to lead the conversation with the user.